# Compresssing Error Unexpected character `

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some jQuery and JavaScript and when I try to compress the JavaScript I get an error saying Unexpected character '`'

I tried two JavaScript compressors but both gave me the same error

I don't know what is the cause of my error:
[image: I don't know what is the cause of my error]

Here is my code:

```
// Login Form Sumbission
$("#loginForm").submit(function (event){

    $("#loginButton").prop("disabled", true);
    $("#loginButton").html(`<div class="spinner-border text-light spinner-border-sm" role="status"><span class="visually-hidden">Loading...</span></div> Submit`);
    $("#loginEmail").off("input")
    $("#loginPassword").off("input")

    let formData = {
        "csrfmiddlewaretoken": $('#loginForm input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
        "email": $("#loginEmail").val(),
        "password": $("#loginPassword").val(),
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/accounts/login/",
        data: formData,
        dataType: "json",
        encode: true,
    }).done(function (data){
        var status = data["status"];

        // If The User Successfully Logged In
        if (status === "success"){

            // Update Navigation Bar
            $("#navbar").replaceWith(data["navbarHtml"]);
            $("#loginModal button.btn-close").click();
            $("#modals").remove();

            // Update Other Things On The Web Page Base On Thier Path
            let path = window.location.pathname;

            if (path in data){
                var updateData = data[path]
            }
            else{
                var updateData = {}
            };

            for (item in updateData) {
                $(item).replaceWith(updateData[item]);             
            };

            $("#messages").html(`
            <div style="margin-bottom: 0px" class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert" id="messages">
                <strong class="text-dark">${data["message"]}</strong>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>`)

        };
    });

    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: You obviously have that character in there - the line setting the #loginButton html -- the character is used for template strings, but you're not using it that way, so: simply replace it with a regular quote.

Comment: @flowtron That would help with the error on line 5, but it wouldn't help them further down in the code where they're changing the HTML of #messages.

Comment: Heh - indeed; in that case, if the compressor is not ES6-ready, you'd have to fall back to "static string " + a_variable +" more static string" patterns .. may they rest in peace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error `` Unexpected character '`' `` is from the parser of the compressor.

I can't say for sure from which one (the site uses UglifyJS 2 and YUI) but I would guess it is YUI (its development has stopped several years ago).

YUI will fail to parse and compress modern JavaScript, it does not know about `let` and `const`, does not know `` ` ``, `await`/`async`, …

So the solution will be to limit yourself to the features the compressor knows or to use a compressor that knows the features you use.

Which one to choose is out of the scope of StackOverflow (Terser, UglifyJS 3 and Google Closure Compiler are possible candidates all with their pros and cons)

Comment: Indeed not all are up to snuff with ES6!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer i am really new to javascript and jquery and i did not know about stuff like ES6 and all i found that this tool solved my problem by digital ocean https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tools/minify

Comment: @Arkodeep JavaScript is the commonly used name for the programming language specified by ECMAScript (ES). So if someone refers to ES1 - ES5, ES2015-ES2022, then this person talks about a specific version of JavaScript. `let` was introduced in ES2015 (often referred to as ES6)